# users not able to post to discussion board

Tags: nodes

I have a simple forum in Drupal 6 that has 3 containers.  From the admin perspective I can easily post a comment in either of the 3 containers.  However authenticated users are unable to post to any container.  The drop down box that allows you to select the container within the forum does not appear for authenticated users. I have attached a screen shot showing the difference between the two.  Yes, user permissions are all turned on to enter content for the discussion board.  Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Drupal 6 site handy to check this but the problem should be caused by either authenticated user permissions (global Drupal permissions) or if you are using field-specific permissions, that would also prevent a user from seeing that field. Please check what permissions authenticated user has for taxonomy related actions (I'm assuming you are using taxonomy to display forum containers?)

Comment: Thank you Kaisia W.  Yes, I am using Taxonomy to display forum containers.  I have the correct permissions in place (both globally and for Taxonomy) and I still run into the same issue.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Are you using a module like Taxonomy Access Control or some other modules that may override the core permissions?

Comment: Yes, I am using Taxonomy Access Control.

Comment: That's the source of your problem, most likely. Taxonomy Access Control overrides the Drupal core permissions by blocking access to view and edit taxonomy terms to specific roles. You may have to manipulate the permissions in that Taxonomy Access Control module to allow authenticated users to view/edit that particular taxonomy.

Comment: Kasia, that solved the problem of having the users be able to post to the message board.  Thank you!  But now, I am getting a message when they log in that says "No Forums Defined".  Any idea why?  Thanks again for all your help.